# Pegando informação de uma função

Tags: php

quero salvar as coordenadas geográficas de um endereço, no banco de dados. Eu consigo fazer isso, mas tem um porém.

Tenho uma função que pega um endereço e retorna as coordenadas geográficas do mesmo.
O problema é que como a função tem um "echo" para exibir as coordenadas e ela está trancando a minha aplicação.
Vocês sabem como fazer essa função retornar o resultado sem ser através de "echo" ou sabem como fazer com que a aplicação não "pare" quando passar pelo "echo"?

Segue a função:

```
function getCoordinates($address){

    $address = str_replace(" ", "+", $address); // replace all the white space with "+" sign to match with google search pattern

    $url = "http://maps.google.com/maps/api/geocode/json?sensor=false&address=$address";

    $response = file_get_contents($url);

    $json = json_decode($response,TRUE); //generate array object from the response from the web

    return ($json['results'][0]['geometry']['location']['lat'].",".$json['results'][0]['geometry']['location']['lng']);

    }

    echo getCoordinates($address);
```

Comment: Tira o `echo`. Fora isso não dá para entender o que você quer.

Comment: Gustavo, Tem como adicionar outros detalhes a questão?

Comment: @bigown, simplesmente quero o resultado, a reposta a informação da função, ou seja, as coordenadas, mas o echo pára a minha aplicação... Estou usando a função dentro de uma aplicação minha!

Comment: @Mega, que outros detalhes você precisa?
O que mais posso detalhar é que estou rodando a função dentro de uma aplicação.

Answer (score 1):

Se isso é arquivo chamado várias vezes, deixa apenas essa função no arquivo e faça o echo nos demais arquivos se não for possível, ligue o buffer de saída para evitar o erro do headers aready sent com ob_start();

```
ob_start();
echo getCoordinates($address);
```

Comment: Não se era isso que ele queria, Mais a resposta está correta no contexto que ele utilizou ;)

Comment: Desculpe @rray, não entendi nada do que você quis dizer.

Comment: a tela fica em branco, @GustavoSevero?

Comment: Não @rray, só aparecem as coordenadas e não vai para a outra página como era devido, pois coloquei um header("Location") no final.

Comment: @gustavosevero, o ob_start() deu certo? Vc precisa imprir as coordenadas na tela ou apenas redirecionar elas para outra página?

Answer (score -1):

Se você quer apenas *debugar* seu código para saber o que sua função está retornando, utilize o seguinte comando:

```
echo '<pre>';
var_dump(getCoordinates($address));
echo '</pre>';
```

[referência](http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/function.var-dump.php)

Comment: eu sei o que a função está retornando, não é esse o caso.

Comment: Pessoal, consegui!
Eu, simplesmente tirei o echo!
Valeu, mesmo assim, pelas dicas.